# « 猫をかぶる » littéralement : « porter la peau de chat »

Tags: expressions, japonais

On dit, par ex.:

> D'habitude, elle n'est pas aussi féminine, tant s'en faut ! Elle **porte la peau de chat**, c'est tout.

L’expression péjorative japonaise 猫をかぶる "neko wo kaburu", signifiant littéralement « porter la peau de chat », se réfère souvent à une femme qui se montre tout sucre, tout miel auprès de son copain ou en public, alors qu'habituellement elle se comporte comme un garçon manqué, par exemple, ou manque peut-être aux convenances.

Quand on dit « une femme porte la peau de chat », on laisse entendre qu’elle joue les petites filles modèles, quitte à la faire passer pour une véritable abrutie. Car tous ceux qui l'entourent (sauf son chéri, bien sûr !) savent très bien que derrière sa voix mielleuse et son sourire doucereux se cache sa réelle personnalité *un peu* moins mignonne...

Nombreux sont d’ailleurs ceux qui prétendent que « a wolf in sheep's clothing / un loup portant la peau d’agneau » est son équivalent en anglais, mais ce sont des faux amis.

Quelqu’un comme un loup n’a pour but que de faire du tort ou de s’en prendre à quelqu'un d'autre. Et ce n’est qu’à cette fin qu’un loup fourbe manifeste une amabilité de façade envers sa proie.

Quant à 猫をかぶる, par contre, le comportement apparemment attirant d’une femme vise simplement à ce qu’elle s'introduise dans les bonnes grâces de quelqu’un. Il s'agit là tout bonnement d'essayer de se mettre en valeur, se montrer sous son meilleur jour.

Comment: Juste une piste sans conviction, « cacher son jeu » (cacher ses objectifs pour éventuellement mieux les atteindre, et ne se dit pas que pour les femmes - les hommes en font tout autant).

Comment: Comme Laure, je pense qu' il existe des expressions similaires, mais qu'elles ont un sens bien plus large que celui d'une femme "qui porte une peau de chat"

Comment: _[Une jolie fleur dans une peau de vache](https://www.paroles.net/georges-brassens/paroles-une-jolie-fleur), Une jolie vache déguisée en fleur, Qui fait la belle et qui vous attache, Et qui vous mène par le bout du cœur_ (Georges Brassens)

Comment: @Charly Hi. 猫をかぶる peut s’appliquer aux deux sexes, quoique réservé surtout aux jeunes femmes auxquelles il est primordial de se montrer sous son meilleur jour.

Comment: Sans grande conviction, « faire la/sa coquette » (ou « faire le/son coquet », l'emploi au masculin est rarissime). Cette expression signifie entreprendre de séduire en essayant de se faire bien voir quite à jouer les petites filles/garçons modèles, faire cas d'un rien.

Comment: "Faire sa sainte Nitouche" qui signifie être hypocrite, faire semblant de "ne pas y toucher", jouer l'innocente. Ca ne s'emploie que pour une femme, à ma connaissance, ou en tout cas toujours au féminin.

Comment: @Alone-zee, thanks a lot. I hope the bounty will simultaneously provide more information about your question.

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens Btw I'm French and I have no idea what "tant s'en faut" means, maybe you should go for a more contemporary expression ^^

Comment: @TeleportingGoat What?! :D I sometimes place it at the end of a sentence as a replacement for "loin de là". Strange, as I've first hand heard some French speakers from France use it on several separate occasions. Is it a regional thing or something?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens Yeah, it might be regional. It wouldn't surprise me if the speakers were are from Belgium or Switzerland for example, but for France it's weird. What region were they from? Personally, I'd use "*loin de là*" here. ((I'll say it again, but it's not that I don't use it often, I've never heard it orally and I had to look it up because I really didn't know what it meant ^^))

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Check out my question for details, buddy. :)

Comment: I guess you could use "minauder" in some contexts; which is generally associated with a seductive attitude but not necessarily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Un peu subjectif, mais je pense que **"faire patte de velours"** a un sens assez proche de ce qui est décrit dans la question et présente l'avantage de faire référence au chat également.

De plus amples informations [ici](http://www.expressions-francaises.fr/expressions-f/2647-faire-patte-de-velours.html), que je recopie ci-dessous:

> **Faire patte de velours**
>
> **Signification** : Se donner une apparence douce et inoffensive, se
> montrer aimable et arrangeant malgré ses sentiments pour obtenir
> quelque chose.
>
> **Origine** : Expression française qui remonte au milieu du XVIIème
> siècle, longuement utilisée en parlant du chat pour prendre ensuite et
> par métaphore relative à l’animal en question qui se donne une
> apparence douce et inoffensive mais qui peut toutefois blesser. En
> effet, le chat est parmi les animaux celui qui peut retirer ses
> griffes et les ressortir à volonté.
>
> **Exemple d’utilisation** : Faire la patte de velours, manière de parler
> figurée pour flatter ou caresser quelqu’un. Et de peur de les blesser
> faisait patte de velours. (D’Ablancourt : Dictionnaire comique)

En complément, je propose également **"faire la sainte nitouche"** (que j'indiquais dans les commentaires). En effet, il me semble que "faire patte de velours" ne reflète pas suffisamment l'aspect péjoratif de l'expression qu'on retrouve mieux ici. La définition [ici](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/sainte-nitouche).

Et, même [source](http://www.expressions-francaises.fr/expressions-f/987-faire-la-sainte-nitouche.html?highlight=WyJuaXRvdWNoZSJd).

> **Faire la sainte nitouche**
>
> **Signification**: "faire la sainte nitouche"
> signifie jouer la femme chaste et innocente et par extension fait
> allusion à celle qui cache ses défauts pour se donner un air innocent.
>
> **Origine**: cette expression française née et popularisée par Rabelais
> dans Gargantua au milieu du XVIème siècle donne un air d'innocence
> mêlé à une idée de fausseté et d'hypocrisie. Afin de mieux comprendre
> ses origines , il serait logique de définir les termes qui la
> composent selon les dictionnaires de l'époque. Une sainte est une
> personne dont la vie est exemplaire et qui a été canonisée selon les
> principes de la religion chrétienne. Elle aurait vêcu selon des
> préceptes de vertu et de respect de son prochain. Elle n'approcherait
> pas les plaisirs charnels et se consacrerait aux nourritures
> spirituelles. La "sainte nitouche" est celle qui se veut être
> innocente, irréprochable alors que tous ceux qui l'entourent
> connaissent sa véritable nature.

Le texte de [Rabelais](http://abu.cnam.fr/cgi-bin/donner_html?gargantua2) de 1534, en français de l'époque "Saincte Nytouche" (chapitre 27).

Comment: http://blog.ted.com/40-idioms-that-cant-be-translated-literally/comment-page-9/ Salut. Ce site prétend qu’il n’existe aucun équivalent à 猫をかぶる, et pour cause. Pourtant, à mes yeux, « sainte nitouche » est bel et bien ce qui s’en rapproche le plus. ;)

Comment: Bonjour Alone-zee, en utilisant Google avec "Neko kaburu sainte nitouche", on arrive à trouver quelques liens, comme celui-ci: http://www.eudict.com/?lang=japfre&word=neko%20wo%20kaburu